# Извлечение значений из массива (js)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, массивы, post

Я отправляю post-запрос на сервер, а php даёт в ответ массив, но значения из массива я извлечь не могу

Передаю 2 значения с php-сервера на js вот таким образом (PHP):

```
$idp = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT idp FROM videos WHERE idv = '$idv'"))['idp'];
    $p = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT login FROM accounts WHERE idp = '$idp'"))['login'];
    $data = [
        0 => $idp,
        1 => $p
    ];
    $data = json_encode($data);
    echo($data);
```

А извлекаю так:

```
function(arr){
                                var idp = arr[0];
                                var p = arr[1];
```

Но получаю я не те значения, что передаю, что не так и как исправить?

Comment: а то что вам возвращаеться вы в консоль вывести пытались ? продебажить мб ?

Answer (score 1):

Полученный arr нужно прогнать через json.parse(arr).
И при полях idv и idp в БД не unique лучше добавить к запросам LIMIT 1. Ну и через f12 клавишу в хроме, например, смотреть, что приходит.

Comment: Ошибка: `json is not defined` код: `arr = json.parse(arr);`

Comment: В internet explorer?

Comment: Извиняюсь, JSON вместо json

Comment: Окееей, теперь за место значений там `[object Object]`, значения никак не извлечь, выводит `NaN`